# Соритровка словаря

Tags: python

Имеется словарь вида:

```
d = {'c': 'test1', 'a': 'test2', 'b': ['test3', 'test4']}
```

Я написал функцию, которая его сортирует:

```
def sort_d():
    sorted_d = sorted(d.items())
    d = dict(sorted_d)
    retrun d
```

ПО итогу хочу получить отсортированный словарь в переменной d, но получаю ошибку:`UnboundLocalError: local variable 'd' referenced before assignment`
Я не понимаю, как её можно исправить? sorted_d спокойной можно вернуть, а вот с изменеием d возникает проблема.

Comment: Для начала определитесь, переменная `d` — глобальная или локальная внутри функции? Если глобальная, значит не надо её создавать внутри функции (да и вообще нет смысла создавать функцию). Если локальная — значит её надо передать в функцию извне в качестве параметра

Comment: А вообще весь код записывается в одну строку `d = dict(sorted(d.items()))`

Comment: @andreymal Мне нужно через свою функцию реализовать сортировку словаря, при этом вернуть из неё уже сортированный словарь в ту же переменную, где он был изначально. Ваш код не дает "постоянного" эффекта.

Comment: Что такое "постоянный" эффект?

Comment: @andreymal т.е. изначально у меня есть словарь а (не отсортированный). После выполнения функции я хочу получить словарь а (отсортированный). Но уже не только в рамках функции сортировки, а вообще в коде.

Comment: Показанная мной одна строка даёт именно такой эффект

Comment: Но если вам прям уж очень-очень нужна именно функция, то `sort_d = lambda d: dict(sorted(d.items()))` (где `d` это аргумент/параметр функции и локальная переменная — см. первый комментарий)